# Cannot connect to database - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, playframework

When I run my localhost Play server I get the message:
Cannot connect to database [default].

My build.sbt:

```
name := """myFirstProj"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
cache,
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.3.jre7",
javaWs)
```

And my application's conf:

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
default.username = postgres  
default.password = "XXXX"
```

My posgres \conninfo

```
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" on host "localhost" at port "5432".
```

Comment: Maybe more detailed exception string would be useful?

Comment: It says sometimes: datasource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.